# data.medicare.gov/resource/4pq5-n9py.json Numbers as Dates

Tags: socrata, soda

Calling the API https://data.medicare.gov/resource/4pq5-n9py.json returns erratic results.

```
{
  ...
  "reported_cna_staffing_hours_per_resident_per_day" : "2.53304",
  "cycle_2_number_of_complaint_health_deficiencies" : "2017-06-22T00:00:00",
  "cycle_2_health_deficiency_score" : "0",
  ...
}
```

I believe `cycle_2_number_of_complaint_health_deficiencies` should be a number. The data on the website is correct so I'm assuming that it is a problem with the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that field is defined as a floating timestamp. It appears the human readable name, `Rating Cycle 1 Standard Survey Health Date`, differs from the API name which you see on the API call. Looks like it's more an issue with confusing naming conventions.

Take a look at the [metadata page](https://data.medicare.gov/Nursing-Home-Compare/Provider-Info/4pq5-n9py) for the underlying API names.

Comment: I'll pass this on to our support team and see if they can alert the customer. Thanks Tom!

Comment: @chrismetcalf can you also ask them to correct Rating Cycle 1 Health Revisit Score it's field name cycle_2_standard_health_survey_date sounds like a date.

Comment: @chrismetcalf Also we have SSIS packages that have run for years assuming that that field was a number. Did something change?

Comment: @motkohn it can be changed anytime by the dataset owner. Given how all the names are shifted and misaligned between the human name versus the API name, my guess is that they recently reorganized columns. I would recommend clicking "Contact Dataset Owner" to email them directly.

Comment: I contacted as @TomSchenkJr recommended and they fixed it. thanks